# How to compare preg_match outputs?

Tags: php, preg-match

So what I am trying to do is read from the txt document addresses.txt which looks something like this

```
[9677]  1F8gYXp2EogDAymQYu4eFQpCxRF3kz6GJi  balance= 5000000  
[9681]  1C9BXAXYjb6W12RSmrpsrAUYPBB7n59ssq  balance= 10673000
```

and take the plain numbers "9677" and "9681" and compare them, the thing I get is print_r output of this numbers from where I cannot compare them. The PHP code is below:

```
<?php
$lines = file("addresses.txt");

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $regex = '~\[(.*?)\]\s*~';

    preg_match($regex , $line, $match);

    print_r($match[1]);
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Save the matched number in a variable?!

Comment: what is the goal of such "comparing" ? do you want to sort that numbers?

Comment: $Match is overwritten  each time the loop runs. Maybe you can use preg_match_all? This way all matches will be saved in $match? But then you need to run preg_match_all on the full text file and not line by line

Comment: I can give you the code how I think when I get home, but that is in one hour..

Comment: I need to compare each lines first 3 or 4 numbers depends on the line with the previous one 3 or 4 numbers, check if the difference between them is 20 or more and if it is print out the whole line.

Comment: I think you should include your last comment into your question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 $Adresses = file_get_contents("addresses.txt");

 Preg_match_all("/\[(\d+)\]\s.*/", $Adresses, $Match);
 var_dump($Match);

 for ($x=0;$x<=count($Match[1])-2;$x++){
     if(($Match[1][$x]-$Match[1][$x+1]) >=20 || ($Match[1][$x+1]-$Match[1][$x]) >=20){
         Echo $Match[0][$x] . "<br>";
         Echo $Match[0][$x+1] . "<br><br>";
      }
  }
```

Input:

```
[9677]  1F8gYXp2EogDAymQYu4eFQpCxRF3kz6GJi  balance= 5000000
[9681]  1C9BXAXYjb6W12RSmrpsrAUYPBB7n59ssq  balance= 10673000
[9977]  1F8gYXp2EogDAymQYu4eFQpCxRF3kz6GJi  balance= 5000000
[9681]  1C9BXAXYjb6W12RSmrpsrAUYPBB7n59ssq  balance= 10673000
[9127]  1F8gYXp2EogDAymQYu4eFQpCxRF3kz6GJi  balance= 5000000
[9121]  1C9BXAXYjb6W12RSmrpsrAUYPBB7n59ssq  balance= 10673000
```

Output:

```
[9681] 1C9BXAXYjb6W12RSmrpsrAUYPBB7n59ssq balance= 10673000 
[9977] 1F8gYXp2EogDAymQYu4eFQpCxRF3kz6GJi balance= 5000000 

[9977] 1F8gYXp2EogDAymQYu4eFQpCxRF3kz6GJi balance= 5000000 
[9681] 1C9BXAXYjb6W12RSmrpsrAUYPBB7n59ssq balance= 10673000 

[9681] 1C9BXAXYjb6W12RSmrpsrAUYPBB7n59ssq balance= 10673000 
[9127] 1F8gYXp2EogDAymQYu4eFQpCxRF3kz6GJi balance= 5000000
```

Comment: no, not really.. however I solved it at the end. Here's my code

<?php
$lines = file("addresses.txt");

$i=0;
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
   $regex = '~\[(.*?)\]\s*~';

preg_match($regex , $line, $match);
if((($match[1]-$i)>=20) && ($i!=0)){
 echo "$line";
 echo"<br>";
}

$i = $match[1];

    }

?>

Comment: That is not how you explained it!! You said compare one line with the other and if the difference between them is more than 20.... in your code you only compare it with 20. SIGH.. why did I even spend time on this. Next time, make sure you explain what you want. This is probably the shittiest explanation ever.

Comment: You can answer your own question now if you want.

Comment: don't be frustrated for not being able to understand the question. My solution that I've posted does exactly what I asked in the question, run the code and you'll see it. What is the code you posted doing anyway, what you tried there?

Comment: Where do you fullfill this: "check if the difference between them is 20"?

Comment: this line
if((($match[1]-$i)>=20) 

$match[1] would be the value from the current loop and $i keeps the value of the previous loop.

Comment: You wrote difference between them. Again: difference between them. And them, refers to number in line and previous line according to your comment. How can this mean "if the number is higher than 20"? Anyways, don't expect any help from me again